# Invalid Use Of Property Error. What am I missing?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a UserForm with two options Budget or Actual. If I select Actual the code works and Calls the Sub Routine Actual however if I select Budget I receive the error Invalid Use Of Property at the line Call Budget.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Budget_Click()
    Call Budget
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButtonActual_Click()
    Call Actual
End Sub
```

The Budget Sub Routine

Sub Budget()

```
Dim sys As Object

'Check to see if session is open
 Set sys = CreateObject("BZWhll.WhllObj")
 ResultCode = sys.Connect("B")
 If (ResultCode) Then
 MsgBox "UNABLE TO CONNECT TO  SESSION!"
 MsgBox "MACRO STOPPED!"
 GoTo endM
 End If
  sys.Disconnect


  X203BudgetExtract

  endM:

 End Sub
```

Comment: where does this error occur? which line?

Comment: What line throws the error? Also, when you click the Budget option, which sub is triggered?

Comment: And where's the  call  sub procedures? Can post

Comment: @Shrikant the line Call Budget is highlighted.

Comment: Your code is not enough to trouble shoot. Add more information like method implementation etc.

Comment: can you provide us the code for Sub Budget ?

Comment: @Zac The Budget sub routine is triggered. The Budget sub routine sits in Module 5.

Comment: The prob is in Budget Sub , kindly provide the code for Budget so that we can figure it out.

Comment: @Shrikant see code added.

Comment: is it `Host Automation` ? then can you please try adding this code after creating object . `Retval = Host.OpenSession( 1, 1, "", 30, 1 )
If ( Retval ) Then
   Host.MsgBox "Error connecting to host!", 48
   EndSub
End If`

Comment: @Shrikant tried that but still get the error at Call Budget!

Comment: can you run this sub directly by pressing F8 and see which line of code giving you the error ?

Comment: @Shrikant when I run the Sub Budget () by itself I receive no errors.

Comment: @Shrikant appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name of the option button to:-

OptionButtonBudget and now my code works!